# Installshield .Net framework prerequisite not installing for users without .net 4.0 or above

Tags: installshield, prerequisites

When I was looking at the Conditions for installing the 4.6.2 .NET Framework I see this

> 1. Registry has value HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full\Release  < 394806
> 2. Win 7/Win Server 2008 R2 (SP 1+)
> 3. Win 8/Win Server 2012
> 4. Win 8.1/Win Server 2012 R2
> 5. Win 10

This works great if the user uses windows update regularly and he/she has a 4.0+ .NET framework installed.

But if a Windows 7 user never updates his/her .NET framework then the default one would be .NET 3.5

And `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\` would not exist. The first condition fails and InstallShield would not attempt to install .NET 4.6.2 on user's machine.

Seems like there is no way to use `Or` group for prerequisite condition. How can I make sure

1. .NET 4.6.2 is automatically installed for users with 4.6.2 below
2. .NET 4.6.2. will NOT get installed for users with 4.6.2 above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the answer provided by [flexerasoftware](https://community.flexerasoftware.com/showthread.php?214179-prerequisite-with-multiple-conditions) it is not possible to do in basic MSI project.

I was able to get it working by using a Advanced UI Suite project and added .NET framework 4.6.2 as a dependency package.

In the Detection condition section config it using a custom Or logic to check whether 4.6.2 should be installed